# Can an Xbox One "GameStream" to an Android tablet?

Tags: xbox-one, android

Can you stream an Xbox One over to an Android tablet? I am looking to find a tablet I can Gamestream to from both my Xbox One and my gaming PC. NVidia Gamestreaming can be done from the PC over to Android but I am not sure if Xbox One can stream to an Android device.

Answer (score 1):

The game streaming feature for Xbox One is exclusive to streaming to devices that run Windows 10. So if you had a Microsoft surface tablet then you could stream to that but considering that your Android tablet doesn't run Windows 10 then I'm going to say no it can't.

Comment: I confirm that I couldn't get my Xbox to beam to my android phone. I was only able to get it to beam to my windows 10 PC.